# Does Ubuntu Server support pNFS yet?

Tags: server, nfs

I am currently implimenting a new storage infrastructure and the hardware supports pNFS as part of NFS4.1.  Is there a supported pNFS implimentation in Ubuntu server?  If so, can someone please provide documentation?

Answer (score 1):

It has been [mentioned in man pages for ages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/blkmapd.8.html). No idea how to use it past [the Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch09s02.html).

I'm not sure it's actually a finalised spec yet so tread carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like pNFS is part of NFS 4.1. Linux kernel has added some NFS 4.1 support. However pNFS support is still under active development.

To get pNFS support on Linux, you have to compile pNFS enabled kernel from source. Source code can be found at [PNFS Development Git tree](http://wiki.linux-nfs.org/wiki/index.php/PNFS_Development_Git_tree)

Then, dependent on whether you want to have the client side or the server side support, you have to follow the different instructions at [PNFS Development](http://wiki.linux-nfs.org/wiki/index.php/PNFS_Development)<sup>[Yanglei Zhao](http://www.quora.com/Yanglei-Zhao)</sup>